# Auto Focus Modes Not Working In Samsung S8

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera, samsung-mobile, galaxy

**Update 2: Any focus modes apparently don't work**

**Update 1: Problem seems to be isolated to my Samsung S8 device. It's working on Nexus 5X and Xiaomi phones**

I've been trying to make `FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE` work but to no avail. I've confirmed my device supports continuous auto picture via `getSupportedFocusModes()`, and not sure why it doesn't work.

Here's my code, continuous auto focus is being set in `startCamera()`:

```
class CaptureReceiptFragment : Fragment(), CaptureReceiptContract.View {

private val MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA = 1

private var camera: Camera? = null
private var hasCameraPermission: Boolean? = null

private lateinit var preview: CameraPreview

override var presenter: CaptureReceiptContract.Presenter? = null

private val picture = Camera.PictureCallback { data, camera ->

    val pictureStorageDir = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), getAppName())

    presenter?.saveReceipt(pictureStorageDir, data)


}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val root = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.capturereceipt_frag, container, false)

    return root
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    hasCameraPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

    if (hasCameraPermission!!) {
        showCameraErrorMsg()
    } else {
        capturereceipt_button_capturereceipt.setOnClickListener {
            captureReceipt()
        }
        startCameraOnCreate()
    }
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    presenter?.start()
    if (hasCameraPermission!!) {
        showCameraErrorMsg()
    } else {
        startCamera()
        setCameraRotation()
    }
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    camera?.release()
    camera = null
}

override fun gotoReceiptList() {
    //TODO
}

override fun goBack() {
    //TODO
}

private fun startCameraOnCreate() {
    preview = CameraPreview(context)
    capturereceipt_framelayout_viewfinder.addView(preview)
    startCamera()
}

private fun startCamera() {
    if (camera == null) {
        camera = Camera.open()
        if (camera == null) {
            showCameraErrorMsg()
        } else {
            val params: Camera.Parameters? = camera!!.parameters
            if (params!!.getSupportedFocusModes()
                    .contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)) {
                params.focusMode = Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE;
            }
            camera?.parameters = params
            preview.camera = camera
            capturereceipt_textview_cameraerrormsg.visibility = View.GONE
            capturereceipt_framelayout_viewfinder.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
}

private fun showCameraErrorMsg() {
    capturereceipt_textview_cameraerrormsg.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    capturereceipt_framelayout_viewfinder.visibility = View.GONE
}

override fun captureReceipt() {
    camera?.takePicture(null, null, picture)
}

private fun getOutputPictureFile(): File? {
    val appName = getAppName()

    val pictureStorageDir = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), appName)

    if (!pictureStorageDir.exists()) {
        pictureStorageDir.mkdirs()
    }

    val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
    return File(pictureStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg")
}

private fun getAppName(): String {
    val appInfo = context.getApplicationInfo()
    val stringId = appInfo.labelRes
    if (stringId == 0) {
        return appInfo.nonLocalizedLabel.toString()
    } else {
        return this.getString(stringId)
    }
}

fun setCameraDisplayOrientation() {
    val info = Camera.CameraInfo()
    Camera.getCameraInfo(CAMERA_FACING_BACK, info)
    val rotation = activity.windowManager.defaultDisplay.rotation
    var degrees = 0
    when (rotation) {
        Surface.ROTATION_0 -> degrees = 0
        Surface.ROTATION_90 -> degrees = 90
        Surface.ROTATION_180 -> degrees = 180
        Surface.ROTATION_270 -> degrees = 270
    }
    var result: Int
    if (info.facing == CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360
        result = (360 - result) % 360  // compensate the mirror
    } else {  // back-facing
        result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360
    }
    camera?.setDisplayOrientation(result);
}

fun setCameraRotation() {
    val info: Camera.CameraInfo = Camera.CameraInfo()
    Camera.getCameraInfo(CAMERA_FACING_BACK, info)
    val rotation = activity.windowManager.defaultDisplay.rotation
    var degrees = 0
    when(rotation) {
        Surface.ROTATION_0 -> degrees = 0
        Surface.ROTATION_90 -> degrees = 90
        Surface.ROTATION_180 -> degrees = 180
        Surface.ROTATION_270 -> degrees = 270
    }
    val rotate = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360
    camera?.setDisplayOrientation(rotate)
    val params: Camera.Parameters = camera!!.parameters
    params.setRotation(rotate)
    camera?.parameters = params
}

companion object {
    @JvmStatic fun newInstance(): CaptureReceiptFragment {
        return CaptureReceiptFragment()
    }
}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why the downvotes? This seems to be a legit question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25321968/trouble-with-focus-mode-continuous-picture-on-galaxy-s5  Related?

Comment: @Michael yes, related though the solution didn't work. I've figured it out already; will post the answer here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured out -- it appears that autofocus mode parameters should be set differently in Samsung S8.

Here's what I tried that failed:

1. Setting any autofocus modes (AUTO, CONTINUOUS_PICTURE, INFINITY)
   before starting preview
2. Scheduled `camera.autoFocus()` to run every
   one second immdediately after camera.open

**Here's what I tried that worked:**

1. Putting continuous focus or `camera.autoFocus()` in a button onClick
2. Delaying the setting of continuous focus by 1 second after `camera.open()` <-- this is what solved my issue

My code for #2:

```
private val autoFocusExecutor = ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1)

fun startCamera() {
    if (camera == null) {
        camera = Camera.open()
        if (camera == null) {
            showCameraErrorMsg()
        } else {
            preview.camera = camera
            capturereceipt_textview_cameraerrormsg.visibility = View.GONE
            capturereceipt_framelayout_viewfinder.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            autoFocusExecutor.schedule(Sc{
                val params: Camera.Parameters = camera!!.parameters
                if (params.getSupportedFocusModes()
                        .contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)) {
                    //TODO: Auto focus not working
                    params.focusMode = Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE
                }
                camera?.parameters = params
            }, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We had this same problem for the Samsung S6 this fixed it!

Comment: By "continuous focus" you mean calling `camera.autoFocus()` every X seconds? About the delaying of getting the supported focus modes, this didn't help me (tested on SGS7 and Pixel 2). It returned me the same tiny set of available focus modes ("fixed" for Pixel 2 and "fixed","infinity" for SGS7).

Comment: @androiddeveloper no, autoFocus is a different way of focusing, as opposed to FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE.

Comment: So, what I want to know, is what the fallback is for Samsungs, if they don't support FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE?

Comment: @BrillPappin I noticed that they barely provide any of those modes. Max of 2 or something like that. So, what we did is just call this function of `autoFocus` every now and then.

Comment: @androiddeveloper you mean if it didn't support FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE, you simply call autoFocus periodically?

Comment: @BrillPappin Indeed. In fact, since I've noticed that I can't even try this mode on any of the devices we had at the office, I didn't bother to add anything related to it in code, sadly...

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with the Samsung J7 Prime, where the code was working but the camera focus was fixed. Setting the focus mode using a handler fixed the issue for me:

```kotlin
Handler().post { 
    camera.apply {
        val params = camera.parameters

        if (params.supportedFocusModes?.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE) == true) {
            params.focusMode = Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE
            camera.parameters = params
        }
    }
}
```