# mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture) does not work

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I follow https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html to activate the custom camera for android 4 but my capture function are totally not working. Below is my code:

**cameraf.java:**

```
public class cameraf extends AppCompatActivity{
private Preview mPreview;
private Camera mCamera;
private static final String TAG = "Myact";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cameraf);
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    mPreview = new Preview(this, mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
   preview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
            Log.v(TAG, "will now take picture");
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
            return true;
        }
    });
    preview.addView(mPreview);
}
private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Getting output media file");
        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        if (pictureFile == null) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Error creating output file");
            return;}
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.v(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v(TAG, e.getMessage());}
    }
};
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;}
    }
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else {
        return null;}
    return mediaFile;
}
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}
public class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    public Preview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
            params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
            params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            mCamera.setParameters(params);
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;}
    }
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }
}
private void releaseCamera(){
    if (mCamera != null){
        mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
        mCamera = null;
    }
}
}
```

And I have add the permission in manifest which is **uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA",uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"**

But from above code it able let me open the camera but when i tap on the screen it become error and cannot store the image. So anyone can share me ideas?

Error:
[image]

Comment: add android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" and please show the stacktrace of the error you are getting.

Comment: Yes, i have add already but problem still same so i remove before i post this forum, about the error is  shown in my phone,which write Unfortunately Camera apps has stopped

Comment: there is a logcat section in Android-Studio, you can have a look at the stacktrace there.

Comment: Hi i have upload my error from logcat there

Comment: @RahulKumar hi, do you have any ideas? if can please share me ideas, thanks, this make me turn into trouble

Comment: there seems to be some binder problem. i am looking into android source code to come up with any solution. not sure though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166615/discussion-between-shi-jie-tio-and-rahul-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

The failure you see could happen because you do not set picture size. Some devices require this.

Note that you must choose one of supported sizes, and also make sure that the picture size and the preview size are in sync (i.e. have same aspect ratio).

You cannot set preview size derived from the surface view size … actually, you don't: your call

```
parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h);
```

is not followed by

```
mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Comment: You tried what exactly? Do you see camera preview when you touch the preview to take picture? Maybe your focus is not ready? Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/26261473/192373 for some special cases of FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE.

Comment: i now remove the focus feature also cannot work, it show me this E/TelephonyProvider: iTelephony is null!!!

Comment: where is the TelephonyProvider addressed?